# How to detect a firewall used

Tags: firewalls, nmap, kali-linux

I was scanning a network with **Nmap**.

I'm looking for **advanced commands** for detecting **firewalls**.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Are you talking about regular firewalls or WAFs? For WAFs there is WAFW00F

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/EnableSecurity/wafw00f but be aware that some of the headers can be change and administrators can fake headers in order to avoid the identification, but is a good starting point :)

Comment: What do you mean by advanced commands? Do you want to detect *whether* a firewall is used or *which* firewall is used? Are you just looking for Nmap options or can any other program also be an answer? The question is very unclear, please edit.